# BotFramework - Logging Chat History for Prompt Dialogs

Tags: c#, botframework

Do anyone knows how am I going to access the rich cards using `IActivityLogger`? Cause right now I cannot log the rich card's properties (e.g. title) though I can access the content by using `activity.AsMessageActivity().Attachments` and access the attachments by using

```
foreach (var attachment in attachments)
{ 
   attachment.Content 
}
```

but I do not know how am I going to access those rich card properties? Any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking to the `ContentType` property of the attachment you will know what type of card the `Attachment` is.

After that is just a matter of casting the `Content` property to the card type.

For example:

```
// TODO: add switch logic to perform the corresponding cast depending the type of the card.
var heroCard = attachment.Content as HeroCard
```

The Content Types of the card are accessible via each of the cards:

```
HeroCard.ContentType

ThumbnailCard.ContentType
```